# Inverting permutations in Python

Tags: python, permutation

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to write a Python function to find the inverse of a permutation on {1,2,3,...,n} using the following code:

```
def inv(str):
    result = []
    i = list(str).index(min(list(str)))
    while min(list(str)) < len(list(str)) + 1:
        list(str)[i : i + 1] = [len(list(str)) + 1]
        result.append(i + 1)
    return result
```

However, when I try to use the function, `inv('<mypermutation>')` returns `[]`.  Am I missing something?  Is Python skipping over my while loop for some syntactical reason I don't understand?  None of my google and stackoverflow searches on topics I think of are returning anything helpful.

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`; it's a built-in.

Comment: "When in doubt, print more out."

Comment: I tried renaming 'str' as 'permutation' and it still returned '[]'.  Any other tips?

Comment: @Wooble: What would you suggest as a name? I always have trouble finding a good name in cases like these :/

Comment: @Fingolfin: Yeah, the naming is not the issue here...

Comment: Your variable 'i' is never modified inside your while loop. Even if it did use the while loop, it won't have any effect. Try explaining what you want the function to do and you'll get better responses.

Comment: You get `[]`? I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, I get `[]`.  I have no clue how you got an infinite loop.

Comment: Remember that `list('{1,2,3}')` returns `['{', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', '}']`, not `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Fingolfin: The while loop can't possibly stop, because you don't mutate (or reassign) `str` (`list(str)` is a completely different newly created object).

Comment: @Fingolfin: Oh, wait, are you *literally* executing `inv('<mypermutation>')`? Then the while conditions compares a string to an integer, which might have a `False` result, depending on the version the Python you use. In Python 3, for example, you'll get an error.

Comment: Fingolfin, I think you need to show a literal, unmodified example of how you call this function to help people figure this out.

Comment: Sorry.  Ended up using the code:
`def inv(lst):
     return [lst.index(i+1)+1 for i in range(len(lst))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want the inverse permutation, you can use

```
def inv(perm):
    inverse = [0] * len(perm)
    for i, p in enumerate(perm):
        inverse[p] = i
    return inverse

perm = [3, 0, 2, 1]
print(inv(perm))
for i in perm:
    print(inv(perm)[i])

[1, 3, 2, 0]
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 21):

Other answers are correct, but for what it's worth, there's a much more performant alternative using numpy:

```
inverse_perm = np.argsort(permutation)
```

EDIT: and the fourth function below is even faster.

Timing code:

```
def invert_permutation_list_scan(p):
    return [p.index(l) for l in range(len(p))]

def invert_permutation_list_comp(permutation):
    return [i for i, j in sorted(enumerate(permutation), key=lambda i_j: i_j[1])]

def invert_permutation_numpy(permutation):
    return np.argsort(permutation)

def invert_permutation_numpy2(permutation):
    inv = np.empty_like(permutation)
    inv[permutation] = np.arange(len(inv), dtype=inv.dtype)
    return inv

x = np.random.randn(1000)
perm = np.argsort(x)
permlist = list(perm)
assert np.array_equal(invert_permutation_list_scan(permlist), invert_permutation_numpy(perm))
assert np.array_equal(invert_permutation_list_comp(perm), invert_permutation_numpy(perm))
assert np.array_equal(invert_permutation_list_comp(perm), invert_permutation_numpy2(perm))
%timeit invert_permutation_list_scan(permlist)
%timeit invert_permutation_list_comp(perm)
%timeit invert_permutation_numpy(perm)
%timeit invert_permutation_numpy2(perm)
```

Results:

```
82.2 ms ± 7.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
479 µs ± 9.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
18 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
4.22 µs ± 388 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Well, if you're going for speed, then you can do less work:
.
```
def invert_permutation_numpy2(permutation):
    x = np.empty_like(permutation)
    x[permutation] = np.arange(len(permutation), dtype=permutation.dtype)
    return x
```
.
On the mini-benchmarks it beats numpy sorting 10-20x

Comment: @VF1 Nice. I've edited my answer to include this even faster function.

Comment: I think `np.arange(len(permutation))[np.argsort(permutation)]` equals `np.argsort(permutation)`.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best way to invert a permutation `perm` is

```
pinv = sorted(range(len(perm)), key=perm.__getitem__)
```

This avoids repeated calls to `.index()` (as in the answer by SeF), which may not be very efficient (quadratic time complexity, while sorting should only take O(n log n)).

Note, however, that this yields as a result a permutation of {0,1,...n-1}, regardless of whether the input was a permutation of {0,1,...,n-1} or of {1,2,...,n} (the latter is what is stated in the question). If the output is supposed to be a permutation of {1,2,...,n}, each element of the result has to be increased by one, for example, like this:

```
pinv = [i+1 for i in sorted(range(len(perm)), key=perm.__getitem__)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just since no one has recommended it here yet, I think it should be mentioned that SymPy has an [entire combinatorics module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/index.html), with a [`Permutation`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/permutations.html) class:

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation
o = [3, 0, 2, 1]
p = Permutation(o)
inv = p.__invert__()
print(inv.array_form) # [1, 3, 2, 0]
```

Using the SymPy class gives you access to a whole lot of other useful methods, such as comparison between equivalent permutations with `==`.

You can read the `sympy.combinatorics.Permutation` source code [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/combinatorics/permutations.html).

Other than that, I would recommend [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737198/2668831) on this page using `np.arange` and `argsort`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I have this wrong, but I think the problem with my code comes when I change `str` to a list:  `str` is a string, and `list(str)` is a list of string elements.  However, since string elements can't be numerically compared to numbers, the code fails to produce a result (other than `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

A "functional style" version:

```
def invert_permutation(permutation):
    return [i for i, j in sorted(enumerate(permutation), key=lambda (_, j): j)]
```

Basically, sorting the indices *i* of the permutation by their values *j* in the permutation yields the desired inverse.

```
p = [2, 1, 5, 0, 4, 3]

invert_permutation(p)
# [3, 1, 0, 5, 4, 2]

# inverse of inverse = identity
invert_permutation(invert_permutation(p)) == p
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a shorter way:

```
def invert(p):
    return [p.index(l) for l in range(len(p))]
```

so that:

```
perm = [3, 0, 2, 1]; print(invert(perm))
```

returns

> [1,3,2,0]

Comment: Note that this is inefficient, O(len(p) ^ 2) in time.