# Is there a nice pythonic way to make an lvalues permutation?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, permutation, lvalue

Let's say you want to make an asymmetric transformation on an array of data, but, you want your data to be symmetric in regard of this transformation. You would

1. make a random permutation of your data,
2. do your asymmetric transformation your permuted data,
3. reverse the permutation to put your data back in place.

Problem : it is much easier to make the permutation on your original dataspace in order to put your data back in place, than to build a reversed permutation.

---

Example : to generate a random foreground color, which is far from a background color, you would need to be far from one of the three fundamental colors and both the other colors may be random.
Let's say my background color is:

```
import random
background = tuple(random.randint(0, 0xff) for _ in range(3))
```

let's choose one component at random:

```
selector = random.choice(((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (2, 0 ,1)))
```

Then, I will choose my first component, far from that one:

```
far_component = 0xff if background[selector[0]] < 0x80 else 0
```

and then I will create my foreground color as a function of my initial selection:

```
foreground = list(range(3))
foreground[selector[0]] = far_component
foreground[selector[1]] = random.randint(0, 0xff)
foreground[selector[2]] = random.randint(0, 0xff)
```

---

In this simple case, things are quite manageable, but let's imagine a much more complex case with many more dimensions. It will require a loop to manage all the output assignations like the following:

```
variable = len(selector)*None # If ever variable doesn't exist yet.
for i in range(len(selector)):
    variable[selector[i]] = ordered_source_tuple[i]
```

Would there be a nice pythonic way to write such an assignation which would look like a comprehension list on variables. Something like this (which obviously won't work because the left part won't be a tuple of LValues):

```
(variable[i] for i in selector) = ordered_source_tuple
```

and finding the reverse permutation to write this is no simple operation

```
variable = ordered_source_tuple(reversed_selector)
```

Comment: This is a great general question about lvalues in Python.  However, could you perhaps simplify your code in this case by assigning random values to *every* foreground component, then overwriting one, at random, with `far_component`?

Comment: Well, thinking about it, it might ruin the example because my point is that there might be many more dimensions and many more than one non random value. But I simplified it another way.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your question, can `selector` and `ordered_source_tuple` have length less than the original sequence (`variable`)?

Comment: No, in this general case, all are the same size. I Just want to reverse the original permutation without having to build the reversed permutation selector. The general idea is : Make a random permutation - modify the permuted data according to a specific plan - put the modified data back in their original place.

Comment: I added info in the main question to reply your question

Answer (score 0):

Create the new color, then permute it before assigning to `foreground`.

```
import random
from operator import itemgetter


background = tuple(random.randint(0, 0xff) for _ in range(3))
selector = random.choice(((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (2, 0 ,1)))
far_component = 0xff if background[selector[0]] < 0x80 else 0

permute = itemgetter(*selector)
components = [far_component, random.randint(), 0xff), random.randint(0, 0xff)]
foreground = permute(components)
```

Comment: I believe you missed the point that is a simple example for something that might be much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating, but how about a dictionary:

`variable = dict(zip(selector, ordered_source_tuple))`

If you want to turn it back into an object sorted by key, you can do

```
variable_list = [variable[i] for i in range(len(selector))]
```

Comment: It is not really what I was asking, but I liked this solution because I thought linearly accessing a list and then random accessing a dictionary might be quicker that random accessing a list like in my example, but having benchmarked it with %timeit in ipython, it appear that this is around two times slower than my loop. If you like, I could append my benchmarking code at the end of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a one-liner, but if you define a helper function as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185908/1718575), it becomes one:

```
def inverted_permutation(p):
    inverse = [0] * len(p)
    for i, p in enumerate(p):
        inverse[p] = i
    return inverse

variable = tuple(source[i] for i in inverted_permutation(selector))
```

Of course, this is more or less equivalent to your assignment loop, but it hides that in a somewhat general-purpose function.

Comment: Well this is more or less the same thing as my loop, but you put it in a function...