# Joint construction of a random permutation and its inverse using NumPy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, permutation

I am looking to construct a random permutation of [1, 2, ..., n] along with its inverse using NumPy. In my application, n can be on the order of 100 million so I am looking for a solution that constructs both the permutation and its inverse in minimum time.

What I've tried:

1. Computing a random permutation and its inverse separately using inbuilt NumPy functions

> ```
> p = np.random.permutation(n)
> pinv = np.argsort(p)
> ```

2. The same idea as approach 1, but using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185768/inverting-permutations-in-python). I found that this solution can speed up the computation of pinv by an order of magnitude.

> ```
> def invert_permutation_numpy2(permutation):
>     inv = np.empty_like(permutation)
>     inv[permutation] = np.arange(len(inv), dtype=inv.dtype)
>     return inv
> p = np.random.permutation(n)
> pinv = invert_permutation_numpy2(p)
> ```

I'm hoping that there is a solution that computes p and pinv jointly and yields additional speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a straightforward implementation of the [Fisher-Yates method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (pseudocode from [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuf%C3%A4llige_Permutation#Fisher-Yates-Verfahren)). When compiled with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/index.html) it's faster than numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit
def randperm(n):
  """Permuation of 1, 2, ... n and its inverse"""
  p = np.arange(1, n+1, dtype=np.int32) # initialize with identity permutation
  pinv = np.empty_like(p)
  for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):           # loop over all items except the first one
    z = np.random.randint(0, i+1)       
    temp = p[z]                         # swap numbers at i and z
    p[z] = p[i]
    p[i] = temp
    pinv[temp-1] = i                    # pinv[p[z]-1] = i
  pinv[p[0]-1] = 0  
  return p, pinv
```

Comparison:

```
%timeit p, pinv = randperm(100_000_000)
# 12.3 s ± 212 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
p = np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, 100_000_000+1, dtype=np.int32))
pinv = np.argsort(p)
# 31.8 s ± 439 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(NB `np.random.permutation(n)` give the permuatation of 0, 1, ... n-1 instead of 1, 2, ... n)

Comment: Thanks! This solution is about 2 times faster than my first option, but it is still about 2 times slower than my second option.

Comment: Well, this depends on your hardware: on Google Colab with GPU I get 28 s for the numpy `argsort` solution, 9 s for numpy with `invert_permutation_numpy2` and 3 s for `randperm`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/StefRe/a3080dd8998c749a914f879e48ad2ace)

Comment: Thanks! The runtime of your approach turns out to be nearly same as option2 on a different machine.